# How to split one single row to multiple rows using Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I want to read the output of below powershell script and split the output using space like this:

[image]

PowerShell script is here:

```powershell
$hostInstances = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -Namespace 'root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer'

$HName = foreach ($hostInstance in $hostInstances){
  $hostInstance.HostName
}

$HStatus = foreach ($hostInstance in $hostInstances){
  $hostInstance.ServiceState
}

# Creating the HTML Page
$Html = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <style> table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; } </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    HostInstances
    <br>
    <table>
      <tr style="background-color: #dddddd;">
        <th>HostInstance</th><th>Status</th>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>$HName</td><td>$HStatus</td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
"@
```

Comment: $hostInstances = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -Namespace 'root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer'
$HName = foreach ($hostInstance in $hostInstances){$hostInstance.HostName}
$HStatus = foreach ($hostInstance in $hostInstances){$hostInstance.ServiceState} .. 1/2

Comment: # Creating the HTML Page
$Html = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<style>  
table, th, td {  
  border: 1px solid black;  
}  
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<br> HostInstances </br>
<table>
<tr style="background-color: #dddddd;">
    <th>HostInstance</th>
    <th>Status</th>
</tr> 
<tr>
 <td>$HName</td>
 <td>$HStatus</td>
</tr>    
</table>
"@  ..2/2

Comment: Please, next time, [try not to post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do away with your `$HName` and `$HStatus` variables and just pipe `$hostInstances` into `ConvertTo-Html`:

```
$hostInstances = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -Namespace 'root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer'
$hostInstancesTableHTML = $hostInstances | ConvertTo-Html -Property HostName, ServiceState
```

This will generate all of your HTML, not just the table. See [`ConvertTo-Html` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html?view=powershell-7.1) to see how you can customise the output (CSS, `<head>`, etc.). The table headers will be based off property names.

Here's how you can customise the header names:

```
$hostInstancesTableHTML = $hostInstances |
  Select-Object `
    @{ n = "Name"; e = { $_.HostName } },
    @{ n = "Status"; e = { $_.ServiceState } } |
  ConvertTo-Html
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Luke answer.  I already had some code written up so I will post it anyways.  My answer will show you how you can incorporate some of the other html you have like the title and style.  `ConvertTo-Html` has some parameters for Head, Body, PreContent, and PostContent.  Have a look at the help with this command `Get-Help ConvertTo-Html`

```
$params = @{
    PreContent = '<br> HostInstances </br>'
    Title      = 'Test Page'
    Head       = '<style> table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; } </style>'
}

Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -Namespace 'root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer' |
    ConvertTo-Html -Property HostName, ServiceState @params |
    Out-File '.\out.html'
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, Luke's script is working for my scenario.